# What is providing the argument in this lambda function?

Tags: c#, .net-core

If there's a list and we have something like this:

```
var myNumbers  = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
var numbersOver1 = myNumbers.Where(n => n > 1);
```

intuitively I can understand that the n argument is a list element. But I'm watching a tutorial where the lambda argument is not intuitive. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

In the screenshot what is providing the "table" argument?

Comment: It's a callback. `CreateTable` will provide the table and call `constraints(table)`

Comment: So within the CreateTable function it will provide the table? But how would one know that when passing a lambda function as a parameter?

Comment: From the signature and it's documentation.

Comment: Datatype I suppose, as lambdas are strongly typed like everything else. Or docs.

Comment: I get it now, thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of code. Copy and paste your code into the question and format it with markdown.